# Find the vector equation of the line AB and find the points where the line intersects the coordinate planes.

Tags: vectors

The position vectors of the points A and B are (1,4,6) and (3,4,7), re- spectively. Find the vector equation of the line AB and find the points where the line intersects the coordinate planes.

The answer for the first part corresponds to (1,4,6) +t(2,0,1).However i cant figure out the answer for the second part.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the equation is NOT $(1,4,6) +t(2,0,1)$, because this is not an equation.  The equation is
$$(x,y,z)=(1,4,6) +t(2,0,1)\ .$$
One of the coordinate planes is given by $z=0$.  Using this together with the equation of the line you can find the corresponding value of $t$ and then this gives you the point of intersection.  Do the same for the other coordinate planes.

Please try it for yourself now.

**Hint**.  One of the other cases is going to end up a bit differently.